# Нужно составить регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть `<input type="text"/>`
Хочу добавить в атрибут `pattern` регулярное выражение, чтоб можно было вводить только цифры и можно было указать минимальное значение n, 9 например.

Я составил регулярное выражение, `^[1-9][0-9]*$` (только цифры), но как сюда добавить минимальное значение? То есть все числа, которые больше 9.

Comment: В чем состоит ваш вопрос, выдать вам готовую регулярку? Дайте вопросу нормальное название плиз. Отредактируйте кнопкой "править".

Comment: Для ввода только цифр существует тип `number`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number

Comment: нужен для type text
type number не поддерживает сафари

Comment: можно воспользоваться атрибутом `min`

Comment: у `<input type="text">` нет атрибута `min`

Comment: полезная тулза https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все числа больше 9 `^[1-9]+[0-9]+$`

Comment: Подойдет и `^[1-9]\d+$`

Comment: Вы указали в вопросе `указать минимальное значение n, 9 например`, а Ваш вариант не позволяет использовать 9 :)

Comment: Причтайте вопрос внимательно :) 9 например! Все числа болье 9

Answer (score 1):

Используйте диапазоны символов с логической комбинацией `ИЛИ` для указания минимального и максимального значения:

- `[1-9]` мин. 1, макс. 9
- `([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])` мин. 1, макс. 99
- `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` мин. 0, макс. 255

#### Ссылки по теме

- [примеры числовых диапазонов](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)
- [разъяснение наборов символов на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set)
- [логическое ИЛИ в регулярных выражениях](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or)

Answer (score 1):

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
* + * { margin-top: 8px; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="9|[1-9][0-9]+" autofocus placeholder=">= 9">
<input pattern="3(6[5-9]|[7-9][0-9])|[4-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,}" placeholder=">= 365">
```